# Using TFS Build to Deploy Console Application with Continuous Integration

Tags: deployment, msbuild, console-application, release-management

I have a solution that contains a number of projects.  Some MVC Web Applications, Some Class Libraries and some Console Applications.

For the Web Applications we simply used Publish Profiles and created TFS Builds referring to those profiles for building deployment packages.  We then used those to deploy the web apps.

How can I configure the Build Definition to give me the same results for my console applications?

The desired result here is to try and work towards automatic deployments using TFS and Release Management.

**Update:**

Ok, It seems I need to explain myself better.

We use TFS (MSBuild) to build the project. By simply "checking in" the code, it triggers our build which builds the project and creates a nice Website_Package.zip file in the drop folder.

What I am looking for, is for MSBuild to do the same for my Console Application. ie. I want it to produce a "ConsoleApp_Package.zip" file and dump it into my drop folder.

Comment: There is no 'standard' deploy package for (Windows) Console apps. You may Zip them or build an MSI.
Explain what are you ooking for.

Comment: I added a bit more explanation, hope that clarifies things

Comment: I go with creating a NuGet package instead of just a zip. Then you can use Chocolately to deploy it!

Comment: I'm curious to know where you see the "results" of the publish profiles (aka build results for the deploy step).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Zip task from MSBuild Extension Pack at http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/.
See http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.8.0/index.html for an example.

Comment: That look promising, I will look into it a bit more and revert back.  Searching for "zip" on their wiki didn't render much help, but I saw in the description it is available.

Comment: In the end I couldn't really find any helpful documentation on this.  The link points to the extension, but when searching, I got no results on the zip package except a change log to say it is there.

Answer (score 0):

You should just build, using MSBuild task, filling the Project with your console app .csproj and leave MSBuild Arguments empty.
Then you use a Copy Files task to get your files from bin folder to staging directory.

Example:

Source Folder: \bin\$(BuildConfiguration)

Contents: **

Target Folder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

After that you can add task to zip the files from staging directory.